# where condition based on multiple columns with Max records

Tags: sql-server

I am having strange requirement, In table 1 i have a col 1 and in Table2 I have columns col1 and col2

now i need to query whichever has max number of records

```
Table 1
A      col2   col3
123    xxxx   xxyy
234    ysx    ddd


Tabl2
A       B       col3        col4
123     321     xx      yy
123     567     fdfdh   fjfj
456     123     dhfdh   dsgds
```

Now, i need to compare Table1 (A) with table2 (A and B) whichever has max count of records

example: 123 -> there are 2 records with table2 A and 1 record with Table2B so my case condition should fetch data from table2A as it has max count

Comment: Are you trying to conditionally determine if you should be pulling data from Table1 or Table2?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is you are trying to conditionally return a resultset based on whichever table has the greatest number of records for a provided value.

If my assumption is correct, then you could try the following approach: (runnable in SSMS)

```
-- Mock-up of Table1.

DECLARE @Table1 TABLE ( A INT, col2 VARCHAR(10), col3 VARCHAR(10) );
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES 
    ( 123, 'xxxx', 'xxyy' ), ( 234, 'ysx', 'ddd' );

-- Mock-up of Table2.

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE ( A INT, B INT, col3 VARCHAR(10), col4 VARCHAR(10) );
INSERT INTO @Table2 ( A, B, col3, col4 ) VALUES
    ( 123, 321, 'xx', 'yy' ), ( 123, 567, 'fdfdh', 'fjfj' ), ( 456, 123, 'dhfdh', 'dsgds' );

-- Query value.
DECLARE @qVal INT = 123;

-- Select data from which ever table has the greater record count of @qVal...

IF ( ( SELECT COUNT ( * ) FROM @Table1 WHERE A = @qVal ) > ( SELECT COUNT ( * ) FROM @Table2 WHERE A = @qVal OR B = @qVal ) ) BEGIN
    
    -- Table1 has the greater record count, select data from here.
    SELECT * FROM @Table1 WHERE A = @qVal;

END
ELSE BEGIN

    -- Table2 has the greater record count, select data from here.
    SELECT * FROM @Table2 WHERE A = @qVal OR B = @qVal;

END
```

Running for an `@qVal` of **123** returns:

```
+-----+-----+-------+-------+
|  A  |  B  | col3  | col4  |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+
| 123 | 321 | xx    | yy    |
| 123 | 567 | fdfdh | fjfj  |
| 456 | 123 | dhfdh | dsgds |
+-----+-----+-------+-------+
```

Whereas running for an `@qVal` of **234** returns:

```
+-----+------+------+
|  A  | col2 | col3 |
+-----+------+------+
| 234 | ysx  | ddd  |
+-----+------+------+
```

**Note**: Given the if/else structure, running for an @qVal that doesn't exist will always return an empty resultset from Table2.

For instance `@qVal = 0` returns:

```
+---+---+------+------+
| A | B | col3 | col4 |
+---+---+------+------+
```

Of course, all this is based on my assumption of your actual need.